# noun adjunct order with proper noun

Tags: proper-nouns, descriptive-grammar

Given a proper noun, "Widget", should a noun adjunct come before or after the proper noun?

Consider: "Windows" operating system and a noun adjunct applying to it:

> Enterprise Windows

This, to me, appears a bit "off", because I'm used to hearing:

> Windows Enterprise

Is there a proper way to apply noun adjuncts to proper nouns?

Comment: I think "Enterprise Thing" would be a noun compound (more stress on the first part is a tell-tale), rather than having a "noun adjunct".  It would help us to answer if you could give more realistic examples.

Comment: @Greg Lee _Peanut butter_ is a compound noun, but the stress is almost always put on the second orthographic word in the UK.

Comment: I agree with the rationale behind what Greg says. If you're making up a proper noun (which can have as many orthographic words as you like  – consider 'He who must not be named' [Voldemort], which does not inflect after prepositions), you can put words (even non-words) in any order you like best.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But only a miniscule number of people in the UK eat peanut butter. *Baked beans* is our equivalent (protein for the masses) and there again the stress comes on the second word.

Comment: @WS2 I usually stress (ie don't) both equally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, then UK speakers should also say pea*nut*, for consistency.

Comment: @GregLee But we don't. It's *pea*nut.

Comment: @Greg Lee Consistency? _In English_? // The 'stress' test for compound nouns is a good rule of thumb, but is less reliable for open compounds, especially with several syllables. However, the 'is it in a modern dictionary?' test is far more reliable. And a new proper name isn't going to be.

Comment: I was just kidding about "peanut".

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to think of some more everyday examples.

Let's suppose the product was a hair shampoo called ***DAZZLE***.

And why not make it the version which makes hair glow in the dark?

I think ***GLOW-IN-THE-DARK DAZZLE*** sounds much better than ***DAZZLE GLOW-IN-THE-DARK***.

Comment: DAZZLE GLOW-IN-THE-DARK sounds better for a childrens story.